# How to create a Docker container that can compile Python code?

Tags: python, docker

I want to make a **Docker** container that can compile and run unsafe client-side **Python** code. The input and output should be displayed inside the **Docker** localhost page.

Should look something like this, just not C++, but **Python**:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IG0h6.png

How can I create a **dockerfile** that could do that?

Comment: It can't without being given unrestricted root access over the entire host.

Comment: @DavidMaze What about dropping the Java part and just making a Docker localhost that  has Python installed, and a basic GUI that can run a compiler/interpreter with an output to the client. How can I create a Docker image that can do that?